# Create .deb installer to replace old package but cannot migrate data in Ubuntu 18.04 Software Center

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, deb

Here is my situation, I have two .deb installer `A` and `B`. The package `B` is package `A`'s successor. For user who has already installed package `A`, and will install package `B`, I want to completely replace the package `A` and keep the data in `~/.A` (and move to `~/.B` for future use).

First, to replace old package `A` with new package `B`, I use **Conflicts** and **Replaces** options in `DEBIAN/control` file of package `B`.

Second, to keep the data in `~/.A`, I write a function in `preinst` script of package `B` to check whether package `A` is installed. If package `A` is found, I move `~/.A` to `~/.B`. Then the new package `B` can use the old data of package `A` to perform the migration process. The steps would be:

1. prerm of `A`
2. preinst of `B` (check the package `A` and move data here)
3. uninstallation of `A`
4. postrm of `A`
5. installation of `B`
6. postinst of `B`

Everything goes well if I use `dpkg` to install these packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i package-a.deb
sudo dpkg -i package-b.deb
```

However, if I install the packages with Software Center (gnome-software) on Ubuntu 18.04, a problem occurs. **The old package `A` was uninstalled before the `preinst` script was executed.** The installation steps changed to:

1. prerm of `A`
2. uninstallation of `A`
3. postrm of `A`
4. preinst of `B` (check the package `A` and move data here, **but everything in `~/.A` was deleted**)
5. installation of `B`
6. postinst of `B`

After some investigations, I found that gnome-sofware on Ubuntu 18.04 use packagekit as backend (which seems to use `apt` as backend) to install .deb files. And I used the following `apt` command to install the package and the same problem occurred!

Note: this `apt` method can reproduce the problem on both Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04

```
sudo apt install ./package-a.deb
sudo apt install ./package-b.deb
```

This problem has been bothering me for a few weeks and there has been no good solution. It is still not possible to replace the old package and move the old data at the same time. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Reading between the lines, seems like you have an improper rule that deletes files from ~. That's unwise, and will get the package rejected from Debian and similar repos. Home dirs are one of the few exceptions from idempotence.

Comment: @user535733 What does the improper rule mean? I actually use the full path instead of the ~/xxx path to move the data.

Comment: dpkg must not remove files in /etc on a normal 'remove' - a 'purge' is required. dpkg must not, under any circumstances, remove any file in /home. Installed packages can manipulate files in /home and /etc, but dpkg must not as part of the install or remove.